# JS - Div on center screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem I have a hidden div in css. when i click a button the div is shown. But I would like it to be shown in the center of the screen, and in the position I am in. Let me explain, if I am in the middle of the page I would like to show it in the middle of the page and in the center (vertical and horizontal), if I am at the end of the page, I want to show it at the end of the page in the center.
I need to do this in js.

With this function I can do something, but the div is shown in the center of the page and I am moved to the center, while I would not want to move from the position I am in, and open the div in the center of the screen

```
    function setToCenterOfParent(element, parent, ignoreWidth, ignoreHeight){
        parentWidth = $(parent).width();
        parentHeight = $(parent).height();  
        elementWidth = $(element).width();
        elementHeight = $(element).height();
        if(!ignoreWidth)
            $(element).css('left', parentWidth/2 - elementWidth/2);
        if(!ignoreHeight)
            $(element).css('top', parentHeight/2 - elementHeight/2);
    }
```

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: How do you position your div, absolute or fixed?

Comment: css position: fixed; would place your div relative to the screen

Comment: Position css fixed @Reyno

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, Francesco

```
let centerY = $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() - element.height())/2;
let centerX = $(window).scrollLeft() + ($(window).width() - element.width())/2;
element.offset({top:centerY, left:centerX});
```

in my case it works in a similar task as it should

Comment: tried but the div is not moved, I move to the position of the div.